How to do expansion of Lagrangians in terms of parametrized metric
For a parametrized metric $$g_{00}= -e^{2\varphi}, g_{0i}=e^{2\varphi}A_{i}, g_{i0}=e^{2\varphi}A_{j}, g_{ij}=e^{-2\varphi}(\delta_{ij}+\sigma_{ij})-A_{i}A_{j}.$$
How to expand $
\sqrt{-g} R(g_{\mu\nu})$ and $\sqrt{-g}\Gamma_{\mu} \Gamma^{\mu}$ where $g=\det(g_{\mu\nu})$, $R$ is the Ricci scalar and $\Gamma$ is the Christoffel symbol contracted with the metric.
How to expand them in terms of $\phi$, $A$ and $\sigma$ up to quartic interactions. Any pedagogic example would help.

what is $\sigma_{ij}$ in this case, just the usual 3-metric? Also, would a Mathematica example be ok in terms of what you are looking for or no?
